# How to find out if a backtracking has solutions or not?

Tags: python, backtracking

I need to print the solutions or a message otherwise.

```
def backRec(x):
    x.append(0)
    for i in range(0,DIM):
        x[len(x)-1] = i
        if consistent(x):
           if solution(x):
              print x
           else:
              backRec(x[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need just one solution could return the solution from `backrec` or `None` in case you terminate the loop without find a solution

```
if solution(x):
    return x
else:
    res = backrec(x[:])
    if res:
        return res
```

if you need all solutions instead you could just store them in a list instead of print them. If at the end the list is empty then you know there are no solutions...